# Where to add mongodb code for updating a field

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

this is my first time working with node.js and mongoDB and I was confused with something.
So basically I followed a youtube tutorial ([Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1Kttu53qTg)) and this is the github repo [Link](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqa3R4RHVRQXVla19KYjl5VWNRM1BZalJuRkdtQXxBQ3Jtc0trV3c3Zk81Nlc2YzhnZHFla2VCWTV5WWJNUVNlcnNxZnZ0VHM5UXk5cDAwRHlmRDJyS3dBT2p1eW1JT0pWOUtlUnFIdnNGMm1tbnQxanpzR21OVXBVdkN4dGpBUUdKd3NsVTh3bU00Uzd4NFNEMWxzbw&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fakashyap2013%2FCRUD_Application_Node.git)

I followed him and then wanted to try out more stuff and added a couple of checkboxes representing the days of the week. But I'm running into an issue where, when I try to update the value of the checkboxes, it just overwrites the array with a single value.

So I looked around and found that a command like this might work:

```
db.collectionName.update({
     "tasks.title": "new todo"
}, {
    $set: { "tasks.$.done": true }
})
```

But I'm confused where I should enter this. Could someone look at the repo linked above and guide me please? I think it might be either in index.js or in controller.js, but I've got no clue.

Thanks
Appreciate it!

Comment: Your question is not clear, however the best place to use MongoDB codes are functions. You can make function for each command and easily call the function whenever you need.

Comment: Umm, how can I explain it further. Like what are you looking for? Do you maybe want some more code snippets? Sorry, new to StackOverflow

Comment: But since we're accessing the database, I can't make the function anywhere right? Like if you see the github repo above, my code to update the checkboxes is in views/update_user.ejs Where would I create the function to update the array containing the checkboxes values? Would it be in index.js or controller.js or some other place?